# Endianness conversion cost on architectures

Tags: endianness, cpu-architecture

Today there are two kinds of CPU architectrues, big endian and little endian. So data needs to be converted between the two representations. Each CPU architecture, instruction set in particular, is different and each allows for different implementations for changing endianness. Some CPUs contain specific instructions while others do not.

My question is this, with today's architectures is it more efficient to have data BE and convert on LE architectures or other way around, in order to minimize data conversion latency and thus maximize throughput in a BE to LE communication.

Second question, can the cost of conversion quantified, is there any data on the matter?

How costly is this conversion in Java from a byte array? Is there data on specific JVMs on specific architectures? Is it different on Dalvik?

AFAIK the relevant architectures for this would be x64, ARM, MIPS and JVM/Dalvik. Am I missing any?

Comment: If I get it right you want to choose the endianness of the exchangeable data in order to put the hard work on one or the other platform (for example in case of network communication)... I'm not an expert in the area but I have a bit of doubt that this can not be answered clearly. For example ARM itself is just a licensable thingy and if you buy the license you can implement/modify/customize the processor as you wish and you can build it together with whatever other hardware that can have huge effect on the overall performance for different tasks. You have to measure concrete target platforms.

Comment: @pasztorpisti you're correct in all observations, but there still are only a limited number of platforms, even with customizations so the problem can be quantified. I think it's especially interesting in case of interpreted languages and JITs.

Comment: Even if we talk only about iPads as an example we are already talking about a relatively large hardware family with some versions having totally different characteristics and this family just grows every year. If we wanted to talk about every popular hardware we currently have in popular mobile devices... :-) But I'm also curious whether someone has an answer to this question.

Comment: @pasztorpisti Do you know if there's much variation in the CPU microarchitecture in iPads? AFAIK Apple has their own version of the CPU, but I doubt they tweak every bit it. I don't say they've made no changes, but treating every small variation as a special case is an overkill. The same variation exists in x64, AMD has different latencies from Intel (and i5 differs from i7, etc, I've even found some bugs [edge cases]), but there's still some quantification that can be done for the platform as a whole. So, just like there's data on context switch cost, I think this is doable too.

Comment: I'm rather a software developer not a hardware expert but as far as I know Apple has simply designed its own arm-compatible processor for iPhone5 and iPad4. With these new phone/tablet versions the performance gain was quite impressive compared to the previous versions (benchmarking with C code) but I can't comment for example on how have they changed the performance - power consumption balance...

Comment: @pasztorpisti I looked around, not many specifics seem to be out there, but I doubt they designed very much from scratch. They customized, mixed together and troubleshooted, that's enough work on a tight schedule, designing a brand hew chip that's compatible with someone else's specs is probably too much work. Then again, I don't know. .... but ARM has bit to specify endianness, so I'd guess on ARM the cost of converting is almost zero. Then again, I don't have a benchmark handy. I wonder how long it will take intel and AMD to implement bi-endian mode.

Comment: This can be true, reusing has lots of benefits, but Apple isn't too skimpy when it comes to creating/designing the best new thing and they probably have plenty of money. Since newer arm processors have byte swap instruction (just like x86/64s) the cost is probably not so high. If I wanted a server client app form my own phones then I would probably put the conversion to the server to save my battery life (yes, I'm mean :-). If I released an app for many with my own server then I would save the power on my own servers ;-). If the conversion cost is not that high then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @pasztorpisti I would reason differently. Server is more busy, relatively speaking, so if the server completes the work in fewer cycles, there's more clients per server per second, in other words, cost per client is lower so the client can get a cheaper service.

Comment: These subject of these reasonings is basically the same just from different viewpoints (service owner/user) but its a double win anyway. A marketing manager would probably use yours. :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49305/discussion-between-martin-and-pasztorpisti)

Answer (score 4):

Storing data is one of the most basic things computers do, why only a few architectures relevant? All architectures must follow a specific endianness (such as x86/x86_64) or bi-endian (ARM, MIPS...) if their word size is **bigger** than an octet

However even if the architecture is bi-endian, the endian must be set at startup and CPUs only work in that endian mode until the mode is changed and everything is restarted. The CPUs can't deal with data in the reversed endian. Therefore data should always be in the **native** endian unless you only copy the value and then send it back *without any processing*, or you do some *very simple operations that are endian-agnostic* like bitwise operations

Network activities are much slower than CPU, not even comparable to RAM speed. You'll hardly ever see any difference in speed but most likely will be memory bound

Comment: 8051 is used today, but for the purposes of this question it's not relevant. PDP is no longer used, nor will any similar architecture emerge again (I bet), so it's not relevant. So in short, I'm optimizing for the 99% of the deployed platforms (PCs, PDAs, routers). And you're mostly right about the tasks being mostly I/O bound. But consider something like sha2, which requires all data to be converted on x64, and while most of it is I/O bound, there's a definite cost to this. The time spent swapping could be used otherwise. Speed up the response by a bit, increase requests/sec, decrease watts.

Comment: +1 agree. And fortunately I'm lucky and currently I work with all little endian platforms. :-)